# eclipse error after i installed springboot using eclipse marketplace

Tags: spring-boot, eclipse

I installed springboot today on eclipse and after its giving me this error. I tried uninstalling springboot but that error still apears.
[reqyesting java ast from selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQL0w.png)
went and checked the error log.
got this error:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2022-12-14 10:58:58.294
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ibm.icu.text.UTF16.isSurrogate(C)Z
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaWordFinder.findWord(JavaWordFinder.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor.updateOccurrenceAnnotations(JavaEditor.java:3300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaEditor$ActivationListener.windowActivated(JavaEditor.java:1216)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$8.run(Workbench.java:1005)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.fireWindowActivated(Workbench.java:1002)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$6.shellActivated(WorkbenchWindow.java:2459)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4251)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1090)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1075)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.WM_ACTIVATE(Decorations.java:1521)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.WM_ACTIVATE(Shell.java:2314)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4743)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1480)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2286)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5026)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DestroyWindow(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.destroyWidget(Control.java:782)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.destroyWidget(Shell.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:831)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.dispose(Widget.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.dispose(Decorations.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.close(Window.java:335)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.close(Dialog.java:988)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.InternalDialog.close(InternalDialog.java:651)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.handleShellCloseEvent(Window.java:739)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.TrayDialog.handleShellCloseEvent(TrayDialog.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window$1.shellClosed(Window.java:685)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4251)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1066)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1090)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1075)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.closeWidget(Decorations.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.WM_CLOSE(Decorations.java:1552)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4748)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1480)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2286)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5026)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProc(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.callWindowProc(Shell.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4847)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1480)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2286)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5026)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProc(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.callWindowProc(Shell.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4847)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1480)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2286)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5026)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3643)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$5.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1046)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.lambda$3(Workbench.java:644)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
```

I tried uninstalling springboot but that error still apears. Also installed new java version.

Comment: Are you on the 2022-12 release of Eclipse?

Comment: i was working with an older release of Eclipse. i actually just deleted eclipse and got the newer version and the error is not there anymore but thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was working with an older release of Eclipse. I deleted eclipse and installed a newer version and the error is not there anymore.